# Max intensity of Red in an area of image ?

Tags: matlab

Quite new to Matlab so maybe it's very easy question. I tried but couldn't understand how to go about it.

I have a `RGB` image and I want to find `maximum` intensity of `Red` color in a rectangular area (I have the 4 vertices' coordinates.) 
I can loop through all the different points of the rectangle and find the maximum but there must be a simpler solution.

TIA.

Comment: If you mean finding the maximum intensity of red component: try `R = im(:,:,1); result = max(R(:));` (whre `im` is your RGB image)

Comment: above works for the whole red plane. I want the maximum in a sub-plane ( area of the rectangle) how can I specify the area of rectangle while calculating maximum ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "rectangular area" part. Try `R = im(minrow:maxrow,mincol:maxcol,1); result = max(R(:))`

Comment: works thanks :) put it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting your image as  `im`, you can try the following:

```
R = im(minrow:maxrow, mincol:maxcol, 1); %// extract rectangular area, R component
result = max(R(:)); %// put into column-vector form and maximize
```